# Angular UI month picker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use [angular-ui-datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) as a month picker. But not able to configure it, tried it all. Here is the [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/XRJHeM1CI57N99QLvLKV?p=preview).

I tried to set the modes as

```
          <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-3" 
          datepicker-popup="MMM-yyyy" min-mode="'month'" datepicker-mode="'month'"
          ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" close-on-date-selection="true"
          datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
          show-button-bar="false" show-weeks="false"/>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
          </span>
```

And also as part of: datepicker-options, using JS as

```
  $scope.dateOptions = {
    'year-format': "'yy'",
    'starting-day': 1,
    'datepicker-mode':"'month'",
    'min-mode':"month"   };
```

But that is also not working. Please help

Comment: It seems to be working fine. You have `datepicker-popup="MMM-yyyy"` for `datepicker-popup` attribute on your input field which shows the month and the year when you pick a date.

If you'd like to show the day as well use `datepicker-popup="dd-MMM-yyyy"` for the `datepicker-popup` attributte.

Comment: it is displaying a month, that is ok.. but when the popup opens it shows a date picker and not month picker...

Comment: See this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmqrH

Comment: already seen that... but it does not work when the date is opened in popup

Comment: Yes, it seems currently it's only supported when used as inline datepicker, but not for the popup datepicker

Comment: The real issue I think is that modes specified as literal strings are not supported by now. You have to use a binding. The same applies to other options ['minDate', 'maxDate', 'datepickerMode', 'initDate', 'shortcutPropagation'] as well. Track this [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3155)

Comment: The angular-bootstrap 0.13.0 didnt work for me in the inline mode, 0.11.0 worked OK and I can use the min-mode="month".

Answer (score 57, accepted):

For those people who are facing this issue, I have tried a lot of things and here is the simplest method that I found:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="MM/yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" datepicker-options="{minMode: 'month'}" datepicker-mode="'month'"/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```

The trick is that you must put `datepicker-options="{minMode: 'month'}" datepicker-mode="'month'"` into the `input` tag. This worked fine for me.

Comment: Ugh, finally a solution. Thanks! This datepicker component in AngularUI is totally dysfunctional.

Answer (score 19):

Just write these lines:

**HTML**

```
 <datepicker ng-model="date" min-mode="month" datepicker-mode="'month'"></datepicker>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.date = new Date();
```

**Don't forget to include necessary js/css files from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

These above code worked for me. :) I know Its too late, but it may help some one.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by updating from ui-bootstrap 0.13.0 to 0.13.1. This is my markup:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="DOB" datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy" datepicker-mode="'year'" is-open="dobOpen" ng-click="dobOpen = true" />
```

Comment: This is the fix for anyone using version ~0.13.0

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get this to work as a month picker either, spent hours trying different options.  Wish I checked the source code earlier - turns out the input type is key.

To change it to month picker mode, change the input type to **"month"**.  This works for both pop-up and in-line variants.

Following from the example on https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ you could do this:

```
<input type="month" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />

<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find below my custom directive and html

Directive:

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .directive('myDatepicker', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            controller: DatePickerController,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            scope: {
                dt: '=',
                datestyle: '@',
                datepickermode: '@',
                minmode: '@',
                mindate: '=',
                maxdate: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, $scope, $element) {

            },
            templateUrl: './datepicker.html'
        };
    })
    .controller('DatePickerController', DatePickerController);

DatePickerController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function DatePickerController($scope) {

    var vm = this;
    if ($scope.datepickermode) {
        vm.DatepickerMode = $scope.datepickermode;
    } else {
        vm.DatepickerMode = 'day';
    }

    if ($scope.minmode) {
        vm.MinMode = $scope.minmode;
    } else {
        vm.MinMode = 'day';
    }

    if ($scope.mindate) {
        vm.MinDate = new Date($scope.mindate);
    } else {
        vm.MinDate = new Date('1000/01/01');
    }

    if ($scope.maxdate) {
        vm.MaxDate = new Date($scope.maxdate);
    } else {
        vm.MaxDate = new Date('9999/12/31');
    }

    vm.dateOptions = {
        datepickerMode: vm.DatepickerMode,
        minMode: vm.MinMode,
        minDate: vm.MinDate,
        maxDate: vm.MaxDate
    };

    vm.openCalendar = function () {
        if (!$scope.dt) {
            $scope.dt = new Date(Date.now());
        }
        vm.dateOptions = {
            datepickerMode: vm.DatepickerMode,
            minMode: vm.MinMode,
            minDate: vm.MinDate,
            maxDate: vm.MaxDate
        };
        vm.popupCalendar.opened = true;
    };

    vm.popupCalendar = {
        opened: false
    };

    vm.changeValue = function () {
        vm.popupCalendar.opened = true;
    };

    vm.prev = function () {
        refreshDate(-1);
    };

    vm.next = function () {
        refreshDate(1);
    };

    function refreshDate(cnt) {
        var buf = new Date($scope.dt);
        var bufDate = buf.getDate();
        var bufMonth = buf.getMonth();
        var bufYear = buf.getFullYear();
        var changeDate;

        switch (vm.MinMode) {
            case 'day':
                bufDate = bufDate + cnt;
                changeDate = new Date(bufYear, bufMonth, bufDate);
                break;
            case 'month':
                bufMonth = bufMonth + cnt;
                changeDate = new Date(bufYear, bufMonth, '01');
                break;
            case 'year':
                bufYear = bufYear + cnt;
                changeDate = new Date(bufYear, 0, 1);
                break;
        }
        if (changeDate >= vm.MinDate && changeDate <= vm.MaxDate) {
            $scope.dt = changeDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Please place your respective code in datepicker.html used in the templateUrl of the directive to display the control as per your needs

My sample datepicker.html:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-black btn-sm" name="day-before" ng-click="vm.prev()"><i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i></a>
        <input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="{{datestyle}}" ng-model="dt" class="btn btn-default btn-black btn-sm datetime-change input-day"
               is-open="vm.popupCalendar.opened" ng-required="true" ng-click="vm.openCalendar()"
               datepicker-options="vm.dateOptions" show-button-bar="false" show-weeks="false" close-on-date-selection="true" readonly />
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-black btn-sm" name="day-after" ng-click="vm.next()"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
```

My Html in the final file where i am using the contorl :

```
<my-datepicker dt="vm.requestDate"  //bind this to your controller
 datepickermode="month"
 minmode="month"
 datestyle="yyyy/MM"
 mindate="vm.MinDate" maxdate="vm.MaxDate"/>
```

[image: This is how it looks]

On the click of the previous and next arrows, month decrements and increments respectively

Comment: Can you please look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59122863/how-to-create-a-month-range-picker-in-angular  . I am in trouble. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I was still getting the same problems despite adding the above mentioned attributes. The only difference I had from @LVarayut's answer was that I had `datepicker-options="date.dateOptions"` attribute in the input, that was causing the **DATE** *picker* to still show up.

Removing the datepicker-options enabled the Month Picker.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [multiple-month-picker](https://github.com/morfsys/multiple-month-picker)

It helps you to select multiple months. It is an AngularJS widget so it should come pretty handy to you.

I've mentioned below how to implement it in your project.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" multiple-month-picker />
```

**JS**

```
//Initiate your app module and inject 'mmp-morfsys'
var app = angular.module('app-name', ['mmp-morfsys']);
```

As easy as that!!

Comment: The answer is not relevant to the question