# how to create the ' << Current Month- Current Year >>' in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic2

I need to create a format like this `<< April-2017 >>`  ,If i click on `<<` once the result should be `<< March-2017 >>` and if I Click `>>` once i Should get `<< April-2017 >>`. How to implement this in angularJS ,Please Help me out, I am new to AngularJS.

Comment: (consider adding the javascript tag to this question)

Comment: What have you tried so far ? You need to post your code...

Comment: I haven't tried , because i didn't had no idea of implementing this. @Lotus91

Comment: @AravindBhatK Then start to read basic tutorials. Learn Javascript, Learn Angularjs then try to implement what you need

Comment: I expect either angular or one of its extensions to already have prebuilt date pickers. In fact, here's the same question that seems to be answered already: [Angular UI Month picker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737270/angular-ui-month-picker)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular UI month picker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737270/angular-ui-month-picker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i have tried for the foresaid question.Please help

In Controller.

```
    $scope.prevMonth = function(){
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
  return $scope.month = $filter('date')(date, 'MMMM');
}
```

In HTML

```
 <div class="col col-2 left_arrow"  ng-click="prevMonth()"
    ng-class="{'pointer_events_none':(enableDatesFrom.isSet && enableDatesFrom.epoch > currentMonthFirstDayEpoch)}">
  <button class="button-clear"
          ng-class="{'color_blue':((enableDatesFrom.isSet && enableDatesFrom.epoch < currentMonthFirstDayEpoch) || (!enableDatesFrom.isSet))}">
          <i class="icon ion-chevron-left"></i></button>
</div>{{date | date:'MMM-yyyy'}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could manipulate a JavaScript Date object using the [Date Setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Setter) but it requires some logic, espacially when adding a month changes the Year. You should consider using [momentJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) in your project. Moment provides some simple functions to manipulate dates. There is a wrapper to use [moment in angular](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment). I can't tell you how to integrate moment in your application unless you provide some sample code.